# How to find element on a popup which is not an Iframe with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get a list of user accounts from a website.
To display this list, my script click on a link which show a popup where are displayed the accounts.
I successfully identified the xpath to get these elements from the dev tool console, but if I click on one of the element, the console tells me:

```
Node cannot be found in the current page.
```

You can see the screenshot here:
[image]
So then I tried my Python script, and it failed.

```
list_accounts = WebDriverWait(p_driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                    (By.XPATH, "//div[@role='dialog']//a/@href")))
```

So I suspected this popup was an Iframe, but it is not. SO I can't use the method "switch" to the iframe.

I am blocked. I don't know if anyone already faced this kind of issue?

Comment: I can see that the page is Instagram, but would you tell us what link you're clicking on so I can emulate that on my end.

Comment: @ShineJ Thanks for helping. It is when you try to switch of account. This link is located on the top right at the home page. Instagram give the possibility to switch of account when you have several Instagram accounts that logged in in the past and saved the connexions.